Real Debrid Add Torrent, can't get it to work
I am trying to use https://api.real-debrid.com/ to add a torrent. When I execute my code I get Bad Request response. I have verified the torrent file is correct. I don't have much experience with rest APIs. The docs for the API are not great. Is there anything obviously wrong with my code? Here is my code:
 public  async Task AddTorrent2(string filePath)
 {
 if (!File.Exists(filePath))
 {
     throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found", filePath);
 }
 
     var requestContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
     var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath));
     fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-bittorrent");

 //   fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
  requestContent.Add(fileContent, "file", Path.GetFileName(filePath));
     var method = "https://api.real-debrid.com/rest/1.0/torrents/addTorrent";
     
     var response = await this.httpClient.PutAsync(method, requestContent);
     if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
     {
         string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
         Console.WriteLine("Success! Response: " + responseBody);
     }
     else
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Error: " + response.StatusCode);
     }
 
 }


Is there anything else returned with the error code? Maybe a friendly text what is wrong?

Unfortunatly nothing
